# Build subversion client only

Tags: svn, client, debian

I need to update subversion client on Debian 5.0 and decided to build client from source.
But configuration with parameters `--without-berkeley-db --without-apache --without-apxs --without-swig --with-ssl` returned error:

> checking for APR... no configure: WARNING: APR not found The Apache
>   Portable Runtime (APR) library cannot be found.

If I run configure tool with parameter --without-apr then I get ext error:

> checking for APR... configure: error: --with-apr requires a directory or file to be provided

What parameters I must print for building client only, without server?

Comment: `apt-get install libapr1-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another solution:

```
sudo echo "deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu lucid svn17" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/svn.list
sudo wget -q http://opensource.wandisco.com/wandisco-debian.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install subversion`
```